# Response code from a URL where location.href = '/';

Tags: python, selenium

Currently scraping a webpage using python to get a response code from a button within the page, however when inspecting element for this button the html code reads the following:

```
<div style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="javascript: location.href = '/';" id="TopPromotionMainArea"></div>
```

I'm quite new to this however other links within the same page have the full url showing after "href=" and when using the requests library I'm able to get the full url. Any idea why in the above example I have "href='/'" and is there a way how I can get the response code for this button?

Comment: How does your scraper know this is a button? are there other divs that invoke javascript when clicked?  Instead of this inline javascript what if it called a function that built a url then navigated to that page? ... there are many problems around this.

Comment: Can you provide the URL? More HTML and your current code.